# button link is going to homepage instead of correct link

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I have a website in which people can list some property.
Now all works except if you check your own listing there is a button which should go to an editing page, so you can change the listing.

Now this button when pressed is going to the homepage (probably because it cannot find the url).
The url when pressed on the button is: http://mywebsite.com/?listing_edit=xxxx  where xxxx is the ID of the listing.
It should go to: http://mywebsite.com/submit-property?listing_edit=xxxx

I found some code but i don't know how to change it (if i am correct ofcourse).

file 1:

```
if( isset( $_GET['listing_edit'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['listing_edit'] ) ){
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// If we have edit load current values
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$edit_id                        =  intval ($_GET['listing_edit']);

$the_post= get_post( $edit_id); 
if( $current_user->ID != $the_post->post_author ) {
    exit('You don\'t have the rights to edit this');
}
$show_err                       =   '';
$action                         =   'edit';
$submit_title                   =   get_the_title($edit_id);
$submit_description             =   get_post_field('post_content', $edit_id);
```

file 2

```
<a  data-original-title="<?php _e('Edit property','wpestate');?>"   class="dashboad-tooltip" href="<?php  print $edit_link;?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o editprop"></i></a>
```

Maybe both should be changed, or just one.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should show us what gets assigned to `$edit_link`. The first file is irrelevant.

Comment: Is there some rewrite rule in play here? We don't have enough information currently to help you.